Applying without any Employment Certificates ("Arbeitszeugnisse")
Preface: This question and its answers may be quite specific to the German-language "employment certificate" ("Arbeitszeugnis"), which is a little bit like a letter of recommendation you get from your employer upon leaving a job - but just a little bit. Answers based on different work cultures may or may not apply. Some more context can be found here, but to quote just one paragraph from that article:

Most job applicants in Germany will be expected to show a reference letter for every job they have in their CV (...) and the lack of it will be seen very negatively by many future employers.


I am (and have always been) based in Germany and I am considering to switch my job. Now, I am in my forties, but I do not have any empoyment certificates in the form typical for Germany ("Arbeitszeugnisse").
My background:

I studied computer science at a university (to a degree somewhat comparable to a Master in extent) for roughly five years. I never took on a formal job during those years.

Then, I got employed as a full-time research + teaching assistant at the university while doing my PhD for the next five years. I did not get an "Arbeitszeugnis" here because I simply never even had the idea I could or should ask for one - in my mind, the PhD certificate was a much stronger proof of my profesional skills than an "Arbeitszeugnis" could ever be. It was not until much later (several years, my former PhD supervisor had already retired by then) that I happened to learn that apparently, some (?) PhD candidates in Germany have their supervisor give them an "Arbeitszeugnis" for their time of working at the university department.

After completing my PhD, I started applying for jobs in industry for the first time in my life. I was looking for advanced/senior software developer positions and got a number of contracts to pick from. I took on one of the jobs offered, where I was quickly promoted multiple times (getting assigned a gradually growing team of developers to lead and delegate work to, then being given full technical leadership of a large high-value project).

As this is the only company I have been working for (for roughly 10 years by now), I have not received any "Arbeitszeugnis" here, either - I understand that asking for one is a major red flag for your employer, akin to announcing my resignation up-front. In fact, I was explicitly told (referring to another colleague) that asking for an "Arbeitszeugnis" will immediately earn you a serious call with our boss's boss.
Likewise, receiving "intermediate references" ("Zwischenzeugnis") appears to be unusual at this company - I learned of a few colleagues who asked for one upon changing teams/superiors so they had some record of their previous merits in the company, and they were pointed to the (indeed extensive, but internal) documentation of our annual performance reviews as a simpler solution. I presume they could have pressed for an actual intermediate evaluation that they can share outside of the company, but see above about red flags.



So, this is how I have been part of the workforce for 15 years and do not have a single "Arbeitszeugnis" to show for it.
Could this cause any issues? And if so, what can I do to mitigate them?
For the record, without knowing the answer to this, I'd probably just go for it and try applying without providing any "Arbeitszeugnis" - and if they ask me, I'd explain more or less what I also stated above. (That is, this is not an "I have no idea what to do"-question,  it is more of an "I'd just go for it, but I'd like to know beforehand what might normally happen in such cases" question.)

Could you contact your University to ask for one after the fact?  Paperwork can be lost, so I would assume they'd have a way to issue one even years after you left.

The red flag situation isn’t unique to your current employer, so is not having an Arbeitszeugnis as a result.

@DanIsFiddlingByFirelight The generic university administration would have no idea what a specific person worked on and especially not their unique strengths. Only the original supervisor could write a useful Arbeitszeugnis.

@DanIsFiddlingByFirelight: What MisterMiyagi said - and also, note that I am not at all lacking any documentation that I did work at the university. I have plenty of that, plus of course all the documentation required to show that I earned my PhD degree.

@MNF3000 you say you've been in the workforce for 15 years. Has it ever been a problem before (not having this letter)? Why wonder if it is a problem now and not in your past employment experiences?

@DarkCygnus: It has not, but that is because I have only ever gone through one "wave" of applications/interviews, some 10 years ago. If you start your first job in the industry, obviously you cannot have any employment certificate from previous employers. And as far as I've understood, it is also somewhat normal not to have an employment certificate from your current employer yet - though I am indeed not sure about expectations of "intermediate certificates".

Why do you think you need an Arbeitszeugnis? It may relevant when you look for another job.

@BernhardDöbler: Exactly, I am looking for another job - cf. "I am considering to switch my employer".

I wouldn't worry too much about it. Standard procedure in Germany is to request the "Abeitszeugnis" when handing in your notice. That means that hiring managers are well aware that candidates cannot provide a "Abeitszeugnis" from their current employer and hence they don't expect one.
Since your second to last gig is more than 15 years ago and in academia, an "Abeitszeugnis" of that job would be of very limited value anyway and you have your Ph.D. degree as a reasonable backup. I doubt anyone would take offense at that.
The only alternative would be a "Zwischenzeugnis" (intermediate reference) but in your situation this would clearly set off the alarm bells and there is absolutely no requirement for the company to give you one. Companies don't like writing "zeugnisse" since they are legal exposure risks and hence highly codified.
I would just start to apply and see what happens. If the topic comes up, you can talk the interviewer through it: You don't want to get one from your current employer since it jeopardizes your relationship and the previous gig was a long time and you have your Ph.D. certificate.


I'd probably just go for it and try applying without providing any "Arbeitszeugnis" - and if they ask me, I'd explain more or less what I also stated above.

That would be my approach too. Additionally, you might want to contact previous employers, and try to have that document from them. You might be successful, you might not. But trying - it is not a bad thing in this case.

"you might want to contact previous employers" - as I have explained in the question, there is only one previous employer. I departed there roughly 10 years ago, my supervisor from back then has retired in the meantime, and actually, no-one who I used to work with is still there, so no-one could write that document. Also, the legal requirement for an employer to provide such an employment certificate expires after 3 years, as far as I could find out. Therefore, for the purpose of this question, let's go with the working hypothesis I cannot retroactively get such an evaluation from them.

@MNF3000: Even though all odds are "against" you now, trying should not be very difficult. You cannot really get disappointed (because you cannot have any positive expectation), but you might have a pleasing surprise (sometimes people help other people, even though it is not required by law). So why not try? And if you not get it, just go ahead. Maybe a lawyer could help you competently for understanding your options - but that is a last resort, if no company wants to hire you for lacking the "Arbeitszeugnis".

I don't think asking the university where OP got there PhD 10 years for an Arbeitszeugnis is either fruitful or useful. The chances of getting anything are almost nil and even if OP got one it would be useless.
